# Ошибка SVGO при запуске

Tags: node.js

Добрый день!
При запуске проекта [SVGO](https://github.com/svg/svgo) у меня выдает ошибку:

> ```
> util.puts: Use console.log instead
> ```

[image]

Как это можно исправить?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Привет. Это не ошибка, это предупреждение.
Дело в том, что **SVGO** использует методы, которые в твоей версии nodejs уже устарели, вот [здесь](https://github.com/svg/svgo/blob/master/lib/svgo/coa.js#L293).

С версии 0.10 вместо `utils.puts` предлагают использовать `console.log`, и это предупреждение вы и видите. Текущий мэйтейнер **SVGO**, скорей всего, не меняет `utils.puts` на `console.log`, потому как до сих пор [поддерживает](https://github.com/svg/svgo/blob/a2f77efa531e174af8ce86903831e51ec8661808/package.json#L57) запуск **SVGO** на версии > 0.8.0.

Comment: Спасибо большое за разъяснение!